# Excel file size and memory of large, sparsely populated sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed a way to store a large number of unique elements in an excel sheet (indexed by date and another numeric identifier) that makes retreiveing entries extremely fast. I convert the date and numeric identifier into a combined unique integer, and use that as the row number in which I store data. This meets all of my needs, because I can quickly retreive the data by its row number (rather than a .find or iteration) and did not have to implement any additional code for overwrites (simply change the value in the appropriate row, without having to check for any existing entries matching that row number and numeric identifier).

However, this results in an extremely sparse sheet. I'm concerned about the file size and memory requirements of this method. How does Excel store data? Does it write empty cells to disk when the file is saved? Does it load them into memory when the workbook is open? If no, how does it store data?

Comment: It seems fairly easy to test. A quick example with the first few rows populated or the same number of rows on very distant lines shows no noticeable size difference on Excel 2010.

Comment: I see. I just did the same test, and got similar results. I also looked at memory usage, and see it doesn't affect that considerably either.

Comment: Pre-2007 file formats will probably have a significant size difference.  But with the newer storage formats that save as .xml inside the zip container, such data anomalies do not have much impact.

Comment: You can examine the innards of an Excel file (as long as it is 2007 or later) by changing the file's **extension** from `.xlsm` or `.xlsx` to `.zip`.  You can then see that Excel stores the data using `xml` format.  I would guess the sparseness of data does not change the file size much.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Also, those responses definitely qualify as answers, Alan and Cody; you should post them as such, so you can receive your due repuation.

Comment: Are you using the integer representation of the date, where today is 41450, as a row index? Just a suggestion: pick a date which will be the earliest that you will need and use this as your starting point. For example, 1/1/2000 is 36526. This will make the worksheet less sparse (easier to manage). But I may have mis-interpreted your description.

Comment: Andrew, your interpretation is correct; and in fact, I already subtract 40000 from the date. I use the following expression to give the row number: `(date-40000)*10+id`, where `id` is the unique numerical identifier i described. Since the ID is never greater than 9, this results in a unique row number for any given combination of date and ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-2007 file formats will probably have a significant size difference. But with the newer storage formats that save as .xml inside the zip container, such data anomalies do not have much impact.

Twist my arm  =)